# Search duplicate IDs with some class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function will find and alert about all duplicate custom attributes (for example, if you would try to use `foo` instead of default `id`).

```
function duplicateAttrChecker() {

    var parmName = "foo";
    $("["+parmName+"]").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr(parmName);
        if($("["+parmName+"='"+ value + "']").length > 1) {
            console.log('duplicate', parmName, 'for value', value);
        }
    });

}
```

The full code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p foo="one">hello</p>
<p foo="three">hello</p>
<p foo="one">hello</p>

<script>
    function duplicateAttrChecker() {

        var parmName = "foo";
        $("["+parmName+"]").each(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr(parmName);
            if($("["+parmName+"='"+ value + "']").length > 1) {
                console.log('duplicate', parmName, 'for value', value);
            }
        });

    }

    duplicateAttrChecker();
</script>
```

How may it be modified to find duplicates only with some class?

So, it should work like *"search all elements with class `bar` and tell me is there are duplicate `foo`s among them"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend your class to the attribute selector:

```
function duplicateAttrChecker(className, attrName) {
    $("."+className+"["+attrName+"]").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr(attrName);
        if ($("."+className+"["+attrName+"='"+ value + "']").length > 1) {
            console.log('duplicate', attrName, 'for value', value);
        }
    });
}

duplicateAttrChecker('bar', 'foo');
```

This will search for all `bar` class elements and notify when they have duplicate `foo` attribute values.

The working jsFiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/y6ac86a4/

Answer (score 2):

[Class selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) have the syntax `.className`.

```
function duplicateAttrChecker(className) {
  var parmName = "foo";
  $("." + CSS.escape(className) + "[" + CSS.escape(parmName) + "]").each(function(){
    var value = $(this).attr(parmName);
    if($("." + CSS.escape(className) + "[" + CSS.escape(parmName) + "=" + CSS.escape(value) + "]").length > 1) {
      console.log('duplicate', parmName, 'for value', value);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this a serious question?

> The question is how it may be modified to find duplicates only with some class?

```
$(".myclass["+parmName+"]").each(function(){ .....
```

Ridiculously easy?